# how to change signs gravity or alignment in html?

Tags: html, webview, alignment

i dont know how to change gravity in html. the language of the text is in persian so i changed the alignment of the text to right but it does not effect the signs at end of sentence i dont know what to add in the html code to effect the signs too.

here is my html code

```
table, td, th{border:0px solid black; padding:0px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;}



@media(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
</style></head>

<body bgcolor=#FFFFFF>
<div id=content>
<div class=text0>در روزگاران خیلی دور، زمانی که خداوند تصمیم به افرینش آدم و حوا را گرفت، به فرشتگانش ماموریت داد که به سرزمین های مختلف بروند و از هر سرزمین خاک جمع اوری کنند. هر سرزمین  خصوصیت مخصوص به خود را داشت.<br>ازین رو 12 فرشته محافظ برای جمع اوری خاک سرزمین عشق به راه افتادند.<br>درمسیر خود به دروازه ای رسیدند.</div>

<div class=image0 title=""></div>
<div class=image1 title=""></div>


</div></body></html>
```

[image: on device]

[image: emulator]

what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<p dir="rtl">Write this text right-to-left!</p>`

futher info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp)